# SwingWorker performance

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I'm working on a Java Swing program. Could there be some performance degradation if I use the following approach?

```
jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
      protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        return null;
      }

      protected void done() {
        // do stuff
      }
    };
    worker.execute();
  }
});
```

If I'm doing some heavy processing task inside `done()`, is it better to define the `SwingWorker` instance as a global member rather than a local anonymous class declaration?

I think if it's local, it's created every time `actionPerformed` is invoked(**is it?**). Will using a global instance lead to increase in performance? Any differences in memory utilization in global/local approaches?

Comment: Why do heavy processing in done()? That method runs on the EDT. You could just skip SwingWorker altogether if you do it that way. Heavy processing should be done in doInBackground()...

Comment: What do you mean by `Global` ? In Java there is no such term, either it associated with an `Instance (Class block)` or it is `local (to the block in which it is defined)`. `SwingWorker` is a specialized version of a `Thread` which is meant for `GUI` related updates, here the programmer performs the time consuming tasks inside `doInBackground()` (which takes places outside the EDT) and if needed sends intermediate information to the `process(...)` method via call to `publish(...) (which executes on the EDT)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your specific example, it is very easy to answer. A `SwingWorker` is designed to be only run once, as specified in the class javadoc (see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3854693/1076463))

> SwingWorker is only designed to be executed once. Executing a SwingWorker more than once will not result in invoking the doInBackground method twice.

So in this case you will have to create a new instance each time the `actionPerformed` is invoked.

Side-note: the heavy processing work should be done in the `doInBackground` method, not in the `done` method or you will block the EDT

Comment: A side question, so let's say my task is to crunch some data(also being accessed by other UI elements),and then update a particular UI element, then the approach should be: Do the processing in `doInBackground()` and update the UI in `done()`?